# Eloquent how to return null

Tags: eloquent

I have the following query:
SELECT null as id, null as cost, null as title FROM books LIMIT 1
It returns one single record.
Using Eloquent, I've tried 
$listagem =  Book::where('id','=',-1)->get();// there is no id = -1
$listagem =  Livro::select('NULL as id' ,'NULL as cost', 'NULL as title')->get();
(...)
but nothing works.
What is the correct sintax?
Thanks

Comment: This question isn't very clear. Are you attempting to select WHERE null? You should look into this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses

Comment: The query must return the following:

Comment: id ---   cost  ---   title

Comment: NULL  --- NULL - NULL

Comment: the resultset consists of one single record, 3 fields (named id, cost, title), all of them have the value NULL

Comment: Are you trying to find a record that has the values NULL, NULL NULL or are you attempting to generate an object having those values?

Comment: I am trying to generate an object having those values in the controller. I use the same view to edit and to insert. I have no problem when I edit, but when I try to insert, the view does not recognize $listagem->id. It doesn't matter to me if $listagem->id is NULL or '' (empty). Thank you.

Comment: I got it: Livro::select(DB::raw('null as id, NULL as lido, null as andar, null as colecao, null as volume, null as titulo, null as autor, null as data_compra, null as custo, null as livraria, null as sinopse'))->take(1)->get();

Comment: If you wish to generate a new object you just need to do `$model = new Livro();` No need to involve the database to generate an empty model object.